# Parse a string to array in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, docker

I am trying to wrap my Node.js app with Docker.
One of the things I need to get from the image runner is an environment variable that contains an array.

For example:

```
docker run -d -e DM_HOSTS=['localhost:1234', 'localhost'] someimage...
```

And my code:

```
let hosts:string[] = process.env.DM_HOSTS ? process.env.DM_HOSTS : ['localhost:1234'];
```

The problem is - I need to parse this environment variable to a real JS array.

I tried JSON.parse() and Array.from() and it didn't work.

Appriciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in a valid JSON, then JSON.parse() can be used, how about

`docker run -d -e DM_HOSTS='["localhost:1234", "localhost"]' someimage...`